# JavaScript: how to return the first letter of each word in a string

Tags: javascript

I have this const:

```
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];
```

and I'm trying to return the first letter of each word.
What I have:

```
const firstLetter = animals.map(animal => {
return_
```

Comment: There seems to be missing code here?

Answer (score 3):

Within the handler of the function `map` destructure the string for getting the first letter and use it as a result for each index.

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];
const result = animals.map(([letter]) => letter);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to return the first letter of each word of *an array* (question says 'string').

You're almost there! 
You could do:

```
animals.map(a => a[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, it was _array_, sorry xD

Comment: I was typing a letter wrong (lmao), but it ended up working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const firstLetter = [];
for(var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  firstLetter.push(animals[i][0]);
}
console.log(firstLetter);
```

If the `animals[i][0]` doesn't work, you can always use `animals[i].charAt(0)`. My solution is a more basic solution, but it is better because it doesn't use built-in functions.

Comment: That could work, yeah, but I have to use .map in this exercise

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` the `animals` Array. On each word `.split('')` it into letters and then `.shift()` to get the first letter.

---

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let greeting = animals.map(animal => animal.split('').shift());

console.log(JSON.stringify(greeting));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to get the first letter of each word and use `join` to combine them into a string:

```js
const animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

const firstLetters = animals.map(a => a[0]).join('');

console.log(firstLetters);
```

Answer (score 0):

write "firstLetter" function and code will be:

```
const firstLetter = (word) => word[0]
const result = animals.map(firstLetter);
```